# Display of popup window on tablet is false

Tags: java, android

I am currently building a popup window which should show 2 rows of labels and buttons allowing the user to view two videos.

I am having difficulties with the layout. Here is the popup layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/layout_background_start">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spacer1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
       android:text=""/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/general_video_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spacer1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Single-Player Tutorial"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/general_video_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/general_video_title"
        android:text="See Video"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spacer2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/general_video_button"
        android:textSize="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text=""/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/multiplayer_video_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spacer2"
        android:text="Multiplayer Tutorial"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/multiplayer_video_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/multiplayer_video_title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/general_video_button"
        android:text="See Video"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code displaying the popup in the main activity:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.videos_popup, null);

    // create the popup window
    int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    boolean focusable = true; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

    // show the popup window
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(m_PlanesLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

I am using the emulator to test the display of the popup with different phones or tablets. The problem is that on tablets the "See Video" buttons become very big and do not respect the "wrap_content" setting in the layout. It seems that the popup window somehow respects a minimum size relative to the width of the screen and that the button size is adjusted in order to obtain this minimum size.

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: Consider writing different layouts for different screen resolutions, e.g. `res/layout/main_activity.xml ` vs. `res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml`: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's not respected `wrap_content` because it's stretched between `TextView` and right edge of the screen:

```
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/multiplayer_video_title"
```